# Rounded Box not working CSS

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I tried to round the corners on this div box that I created and it doesn't work. Tested this out on Chrome, IE, Firefox and no go. I am not too fluent in CSS and DIV. So if you can see my problem, please help me.

Code CSS:

```css
.side-nav-menu{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.side-nav-menu h1{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
  background: #3F5671;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 7px;
}

.side-nav-menu ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.side-nav-menu ul li{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;/
}

.side-nav-menu ul li a{
  font-size: normal 1.1em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side-nav-menu ul li a:hover{
  color: #777777;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="side-nav-menu">
  <h1>Sub-Categories</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=18&amp;Itemid=101">Air Sampling Pumps</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=14&amp;Itemid=101">Dust Monitors</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=16&amp;Itemid=101">Flame Ionization Detectors</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=17&amp;Itemid=101">Photoionization Detectors</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;id=19&amp;Itemid=101">Ventilation Blower</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pssz0xv0/

Comment: Advice for better answers. Don't show all of your code. Just show the relevant parts. It'll get you a lot of better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will remember it next time.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? You have one `border-radius` and it is badly placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child elements wont inherit round corners from their parents. You will have to apply a border radius to the top element 'h1' and bottom element, the last 'a'.

https://jsfiddle.net/pssz0xv0/5/

```
.side-nav-menu h1{
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
.side-nav-menu ul li:last-child a{
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: this worked wonderfully, thank you. There was another answer here that worked as well. So it was hard to choose which one. I picked yours, because it was first.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-radius: 10px
```

On `.side-nav-menu` ?

Comment: add vendor prefixes for better support.

Comment: I forgot to put the rest of the code, i had border-radius already, but no change. I will update the code.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.side-nav-menu{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.side-nav-menu h1{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: white;
    background: #3F5671;
    //margin-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 0 7px 7px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/pssz0xv0/9/

Comment: this works, what is the overflow:hidden doing? and which is better your code or the one posted by partypete25?

Comment: @RealPetChicken Because the child elements cover rounded box that's why border-radius does not appear. partypete25 is trying to round the first child (border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; top-left, top-right) and the last child (border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px; bottom-left, bottom-right).